# Writing strings and bytes to a MemoryStream

Tags: delphi

How to write 'Hello World' string, clrf, and some random 10 bytes to a memory stream in Delphi?

Comment: Do you really want to mix text and binary? And what encoding do you want to use for the text?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would consider using a binary writer for this task. This is a higher level class that takes care of the details of getting data into the stream.

```
var
  Stream: TMemoryStream;
  Writer: TBinaryWriter;
  Bytes: TBytes;
....
Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
try
  Writer := TBinaryWriter.Create(Stream);
  try
    Writer.Write(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('Hello World'+sLineBreak));
    //if you prefer, use a different encoding for your text
    Bytes := GetRandomBytes(10);//I assume you can write this
    Writer.Write(Bytes);
  finally
    Writer.Free;
  end;
finally
  Stream.Free;
end;
```

I expect that your real problem is more involved than this. The benefit of using the writer class is that you insulate yourself from the gory details of spewing data to the stream.

Comment: Thanks David, you are right.I was looking at the PDF format description and I wanted to generate simple PDFs from my code and was intending to use TMemoryStream for that. That was my intention. BTW I was thinking for a moment which answer to accept.

Comment: One of the writer classes is surely a better option for a large project. Or at least use the same idea. You want to be insulated from the stream. But if you want to generate PDF, use one of the existing libraries. Much easier. The Synopse library is well regarded.

Answer (score 5):

```
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
  s: String;
  b: array[0..9] of Byte;
  i: Integer;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    s := 'Hello World' + #13#10;
    ms.Write(s[1], Length(s) * SizeOf(Char));
    for i := 0 to 9 do
      b[i] := Random(256);
    ms.Write(b[0], 10);
    // ms.SaveToFile('C:\temp\test.txt');

    {
    ms.Memory can be used for free access e.g.
    // build an empty buffer 5 characters
    s := '';
    SetLength(s,5);
    ms.Position := 5;
    // the position after which we want to copy
    i := Length('Hallo ')*SizeOf(Char);
    // copy bytes to string
    Move(TByteArray(ms.Memory^)[i],s[1],Length(s) * SizeOf(Char));
    Showmessage(s); // Display's "World"
    }


  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;    
end;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `String` is Unicode in D2009+ and Ansi in earlier versions, so you have to take character encoding into account when exchanging `String` data to the outside world. This example code writes `String` data using whatever Delphi's native format is (Ansi or UTF-16). That is fine as long as the data is only used inside of the app, but if the data needs to be saved/exchanged outside of the app then it is better to pick a single standardized character encoding if possible, such as UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you both, I am using XE. @bummi Thanks for your great answer. If only I could accept both your and David's answer.